# Python: Split String if delimiter is not available using str.split

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split below data based on | delimiter.if only single value is available in response(no Delimiter), it should go to answers not in Question column of dataframe.

Code:

```
answers_df[['Question','answers']] = answers_df.response.str.split("|",expand=True)
```

Data:

```
Assortments  | 5
6
product | 8
```

expected Result:

```
name       rating
-----       ------
Assortments  5
NAN          6
product      8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it, the idea of to append `None` in the front:

```
df['ans2'] = df['ans'].str.split('|').apply(lambda x: [None] + x if len(x) < 2 else x)

df[['q1', 'a1']] = df['ans2'].apply(pd.Series)

df = df.drop('ans2', axis=1)

             ans         name rating
0  Assortments|5  Assortments      5
1              6         None      6
2      product|8      product      8
```

**Sample Data**

```
l=["Assortments|5", "6", "product|8"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"ans": l})
```